# Angular sanitize and HTML highlighting of special char

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm currently trying to combine Angular `DomSanitizer.sanitize` function with an "*home made*" Search highlighting.

Given that I have a data which could be entered by users (like most of web site in this world) named `dataEnterredByUser`

I want to be able to search term on this data in order to highlight them for end user without causing any security issue.

## To Highlight

I already had the highlighting part that I had to improve in order to secure it.

To decorate term occurence I use DOM element `<mark></mark>` That I add in the HTML string by using the following code:

```
this.dataTermHighlighted = this.dataEnterredByUser.replace(
  new RegExp(term, 'g'),
  (m) => `<mark>${m}</mark>`
);
```

With this when searching for `233` in `Data with é & 233`, `dataTermHighlighted` look like `Data with é & <mark>233</mark>`

To be able to apply style I have to use `[innerHTML]` property binding:

```
<span [innerHTML]="dataTermHighlighted"> </span>
```

---

## To secure

But as explained in this [Angular DOC](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)

> DOM property like [innerHTML] could cause Cross Site Scripting (XSS) security bugs when improperly handled.

I have to secure `dataEnterredByUser` by using `DomSanitizer.sanitize`.

This is what I do by sanitizing the `originalDataSanitized`:

```
this.originalDataSanitized = sanitizer.sanitize(
  SecurityContext.HTML,
  this.dataEnterredByUser
);
```

Using `DomSanitizer.sanitize` will change any special characters by his HTML ISO CODE.

Then `Data with é & 233` sanitized will look like `Data with &#233; &amp; 233`

---

## Problem

I've managed the search for special characters.
When searching for `é` in `Data with é & 233` HTML string will look like `Data with <mark>&#233;</mark> &amp; 233` which it's nice.

But now when I'm trying to search for term that is part of any HTML ISO CODE, rendered datas are completely broke.

For example:

1. When searching for `233` in `Data with é & 233` HTML string will be `Data with &#<mark>233</mark>; &amp; <mark>233</mark>` because `é` HTML ISO code is `&#233;`
2. When searching for `&` in `Data with é & 233` HTML string will be `Data with <mark>&</mark>#233; <mark>&</mark>amp; 233` because `&` is used as start char of HTML ISO code.

I'm wonder how I can deal with this.

In fact I'm even wondering if choose the right solution.

I've made this little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g2f1um?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for you.